# powershell credential rejected from server

Tags: powershell, credentials

I need to store credential in powershell to be used several times. Here on StackOverflow there are a lot of example, so I took one

```
$tmpCred = Get-Credential
$tmpCred.Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Set-Content "pwd.dat"
$password = Get-Content "pwd.dat" | ConvertTo-SecureString
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential "myDomain\myUser", $password

Get-ADUser -Credential $credential
```

Unfortunately I get this error and I can't find a solution

```
Get-ADUser : The server has rejected the client credentials.
At line:5 char:11
+ Get-ADUser <<<<  "xxx" -Credential $credential 
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (xxx:ADUser) [Get-ADUser], AuthenticationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : The server has rejected the client credentials.,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

Answer (score 4):

I can't see anything obviously wrong with your code, I'm guessing that this is just an example of how you are using it as you mention you need to use it in several places.  Just to check that it really is the storing of the secure string failing you could check using the following, which should prove that the credentials worked before being persisted to disk:

```
Get-ADUser -Credential $tmpCred
```

One option would be to pass around the credentials rather than a file or securestring, using the type `[System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]` which is returned from your call to Get-Credentials and stored in the variable `$tmpCred`.

You could also temporarily add a call to the method `GetNetworkCredentials()` to ensure that your password has been decrypted correctly, the following will show the username and password (unencrypted):

```
$tmpCred.GetNetworkCredential().Username 
$tmpCred.GetNetworkCredential().Password
```

Hope that helps...